# Как исправить ошибку в моём INSERT запросе?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Если я добавлю значение для поля id - всё работает. Но id ведь автоинкрементное поле, значение должно самоподставлятся. Как исправить ошибку в таком случае?

База данных: MySQL
Запрос делаю через MySQL Workbench
Поля таблицы:

```
id int(11) AI PK 
idPoi int(11) 
idElement int(11) 
idEnvironment int(11) 
ValueAvg double(18,5) 
ValueMax double(18,5) 
idPoligon int(11) 
Year int(11) 
Month int(11) 
day int(11) 
Measure varchar(45)
```

Текст запроса:

```
INSERT INTO h34471c_KPI_KEEM.emissions_on_map
VALUES (1061,21126,1,4.3,4.3,null,2021,5,23,'mg/m3')
```

Текст ошибки:

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: `INSERT INTO h34471c_KPI_KEEM.emissions_on_map (тут,должен,быть,список,колонок,который,соответствует,кол-ву,в,values)
VALUES (1061,21126,1,4.3,4.3,null,2021,5,23,'mg/m3')`

Comment: @InDevX скобочки до `VALUES` не обязательно указывать для `INSERT`. Но есть побочка, с которой и столкнулся автор)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в запросе `INSERT`  не указываются явно имена столбцов, куда происходит вставка, а только список значений (`VALUES`), то *Mysql* по-умолчанию ожидает на вход столько количество значений для `VALUES`, сколько всего имеется **во всей таблице**. То есть для столбца `id int(11) AI PK` он **тоже** будет ожидать данные. Автоинкремент или нет - не важно.

Выход:

- либо указать значение ещё и для столбца `id`
- либо указать явно, для каких столбцов идёт вставка значений (т.е. перечислять 10 имён столбцов вручную). Да, муторно, но C'est La Vie...